# AWS iOS S3 Exception: Invalid region string

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS iOS framework and listing all my S3 buckets. While I am trying to find out the region of my S3 buckets, I am getting the region values, but for region "eu-west-1" it throws an exception that the region string is invalid.

Below is the sample code:

```
@try {
    NSLog(@"\nViewWillappear");
    NSLog(@"---------------------------------List Buckets-------------------------");

    AmazonS3Client *s3 = [AmazonClientManager s3]; 
    NSArray *bucketNames = [s3 listBuckets];

    for(int i=0;i<[bucketNames count];i++)
    {
    S3Bucket *bucket=[bucketNames objectAtIndex:i];


 **This is the line where i get exception
 NSLog(@"region:%@",[s3 getBucketLocation:bucket.name]);**



        NSLog(@"---------------------------------List Of Objects in Bucket %@-------------------------",bucket.name);       
    NSArray *listofobjects=[[AmazonClientManager s3]listObjectsInBucket:bucket.name];   

        for(int j=0;j<[listofobjects count];j++)
        {
        S3ObjectSummary *sumarry=[listofobjects objectAtIndex:j];

        NSLog(@"\nstorage class%@  size%d",sumarry.storageClass,sumarry.size);
        }
    }



    if (buckets == nil) {
        buckets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[bucketNames count]];
    }
    else {
        [buckets removeAllObjects];
    }

    if (bucketNames != nil) {
        for (S3Bucket *bucket in bucketNames) {
            [buckets addObject:[bucket name]];
        }
    }

    [buckets sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
}
@catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Exception = %@", exception);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried, for example, to create a new bucket in "eu-west-1" region, just to verify whether you are getting the same error? What about "EU" (it is a valid alias for eu-west-1). I'm just curious, because AWS even lists "eu-west-1" as a valid value everywhere in S3 documentation.

Comment: According to my knowledge EU is a valid value,I went through of AWS REST API and got to know that the sdk is also using the same REST API. In API, they mentioned that EU is the valid value but in my case I am getting Eu-west-1

Comment: According to the docs, both are valid: "Valid Values: EU | eu-west-1 | us-west-1 | us-west-2 | ap-southeast-1 | ap-northeast-1 | sa-east-1 | empty string (for the US Classic Region)" (from the [API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUT.html))

Comment: are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  We've fixed a bug in the SDK where it was not properly handling certain region strings, particularly the "eu-west-1" region string.

If you upgrade to versions 1.4.3 or later of the AWS SDK for iOS, you should no longer have an issue.

[v1.4.3 Release Notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/SDKs/iOS/6379348484015742)

[S3Region.m](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ios/blob/f3954ffd0acdb2110a8f0db1bebfed36c81546e9/src/Amazon.S3/Model/S3Region.m)

Comment: I am Getting issue in version 2.3.0 aslo

Comment: @Sandesh please open a issue on the GitHub repository or on the forums and someone can assist you further.